# How do I shut down a command block if I don't know the coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, I created a command block that kills any player within 100 blocks of it.

How can I shut it down if I don't know the coordinates?

Answer (score -1):

You can disable command-blocks in the server-config.

You can turn it off by heading over to your server-properities. You should see something like this:
*Command-blocks: true.* You should set it to: *Command-blocks: false*.

Comment: And how, exactly, do you do that?